# How to fix error when deploying Microsoft Azure's FACE API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have deployed the Face API previously on a diferent account with no problems, however now I am getting an error when trying to deploy the Face API.

Here are the details I am putting in for deployment:

[image]

Here is the error message I get:

[image]

And here are the details when I click the message:

[image]

It seems the underlying error is "The account type FACE is either invalid or unavailable in the region"

Which is:

1- Very odd because I have created an account in this region before, The Face Docs show this region as valid and its one of the options in the dropdown.

2- I have tried putting 5 different regions (Europe north, UK, US, etc..) none work.

3- I have also tried changing the name I am giving the app to not contain Face in it or API also doesn't work.

4-  I also checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors where it says in regards to a badRequest error: "You sent deployment values that don't match what is expected by Resource Manager. Check the inner status message for help with troubleshooting."and the inner status message is "

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidApiSetId",
    "message": "The account type 'Face' is either invalid or unavailable in given region."
  }"
```

which doesn't seem to make sense.

5- I don't have a support account with MS Azure and I don't really feel I should get one ATM just for this particular error, just to ask them or I think its more to report a bug.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your case:

- Creation OK with `France Central` region, `F0` pricing and resource name `TEST_FACE`:

[image: Example FR Central]

- Creation OK with `West Europe` region, `F0` pricing and resource name `FaceAPI`:

[image]

Do you still have the problem? The only difference with you is that I am not on a "free trial" subscription.